# Udev rule randomly failing on boot

Tags: ubuntu, udev, devices

I have an embedded system with ubuntu running on it. Inside its /etc/udev/rules.d directory i put a file named 99-mydevice.rules:

```
KERNEL=="video0", SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", SUBSYSTEMS=="platform", GROUP="mygroup"
KERNEL=="video1", SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", SUBSYSTEMS=="platform", GROUP="mygroup"
```

So usually, whenever i reboot the system with

> sudo reboot 0

The rules always work and /dev/video0 always belongs to mygroup. However, if i physically disconnect the device from power and connect it again, when it reboots, sometimes /dev/video0 belongs to mygroup but sometimes it belongs to root.

Am i doing something wrong? When searching [the documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev) i found the commands udev test and udev trigger and tried using them for debug, but they dont always apply my rules when /dev/video0 is present.

Edit 1:
I found the following in systemd-udevd.service journal log:

```
Nov 17 15:35:36 s-ema-mob01-l systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Nov 17 15:35:36 s-ema-mob01-l systemd-udevd[262]: Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel command line, ignoring.
Nov 17 15:35:36 s-ema-mob01-l systemd-udevd[262]: error resolving group 'mygroup': Connection refused
```

Indeed, the group is in my company's active domain so i suppose sometimes it tries to apply the rule before it can actually communicate with the AD.
What is the proper way to solve for this?

Comment: These days, video devices get the tag "uaccess" in udev rules. This works such that when a user logs in, logind changes the permissions on the device so that only the logged in user can open it. Presumably, in your embedded world, you have no login process, but you should try investigating how you might start a session or auto-login to fit in with this mechanism. Here's an [explanation](https://github.com/KillingSpark/HowLogindWork).